# command to execute docker rm <none> image on Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins

I need to remove some docker TAG having 'none' values on Windows.

Do you know the relative windows command to remove 'none' TAG on Docker?
I tried this one but it doesn't work:

echo docker rmi -f &&  (docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove them by using their image ids. Or you can do `docker image prune`.